# Download folder in Android tablet not showing anything

Tags: android, apk

I just used an app to transfer files from my pc to my Android tablet. It seems that I succeeded transferring files as shown in the finder.[image]

However, when I open the download folder in the tablet, there is nothing. I see no icon on the screen. weird. Actually, the storage shows that there is some data in the download folder. I'm new to Android dev. What's wrong with this?

419MB in download folder
[image: 419MB in download folder]

However, no item in it
[image: However, no item in it]

Comment: Are you able to show after unplugging the tablet?

Comment: I unplugged the tablet, however, still no item in the tablet. Do you see the pics above. I just want you to notice what my situation is..

Comment: Try to find Downloads folder in External storage as well as in sd card if any.

Comment: I've still tried to find a way to find my apk fie. anyway, I downloaded my app via DropBox and installed it, now it works. Maybe I have to find other ways to do this as it might take really long.. Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this problem?